# Why do Coda and Segno have symbols, while the jumps to them is always spelled with letters?

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music, repeats

Segno has the symbol  and Coda has the symbol . Ok, barely visible, but I thought it was funny that unicode symbols for these actually exist.

But as far as I know, there are no symbols for D.C., D.S., D.C. al Coda and such. Is this true? If so, is there a historic or maybe even a good reason for this? And why aren't they shortened even more? "D.C. al Coda" and "D.C. al Fine" could be just "D.C.C" and "D.C.F."

I would understand it for things that are fairly rare, but these constructs exist in almost all arrangements.

Comment: When in doubt, the answer for "Why do we write it like this?" is usually "Tradition." :)

Comment: @LSM07 - ah, but where and when did this 'tradition' start? Maybe that's a better question.

Answer (score 2):

Coda has a sign. Segno has a sign. DC means go to the top/beginning. Da Capo. As easy as having a sign. DS means go to the segno sign. But is there much or any point. It wouldn't help if it was a different sign. And 'al' means 'to', which is an instruction that's clear. Hardly worth re-inventing the wheel for.

Comment: True, but the same can be said for the symbols for Segno and Coda. You could just write the words for them.

Comment: @Broman - writing out the words is hardly shortening them. I thought that was what you preferred.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm just stating that if you don't need a symbol for DS al Coda, then you don't need a symbol for Coda either.

Comment: D.C. stands for "Da capo" and means "go to the *beginning*". "Al coda" means "then go to the coda sign".

Comment: @Dekkadeci - of course! Forgot to fully engage brain cell. Edited answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim, there still seems to be at least half a sentence missing